# Getting error in my opcode.cc file

Tags: c++, assembly

I am working on a assembler (sic/Xe) and I am in the process of making the opcode table.    I am getting error when I compile it

g++ opcodetab.cc
    Undefined                       first referenced
     symbol                             in file
    main                                /opt/local/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.6/crt1.o
    ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

```
    #include <string>
    #include <map>
    #include <utility>
    #include <iostream>

    #include "opcodetab.h"
    #include "opcode_error_exception.h"

    using namespace std;

    opcodetab::opcodetab() {
        //Populate the map with opcodes
        //[Mnemonic] = (Hex Value, Format/Size)
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_OPCODES; i++)
            opcodes[codes[i]] = Info(values[i], sizes[i]);
    }

    string opcodetab::get_machine_code(string inOpcode) {
        //change each element of the string to upper case
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<inOpcode.length();i++)
          {
             inOpcode[i] = toupper(inOpcode[i]);
          }

        if(inOpcode[0] == '+') // check if format  4
            inOpcode.erase (0,1); //erase the character at first position

        opcodes_iter = opcodes.find(inOpcode);
        if(opcodes_iter == opcodes.end()){
            throw opcode_error_exception("opcode " + inOpcode + " not found");}

        return (opcodes_iter->second.machine_code);

    }

    int opcodetab::get_instruction_size(string inOpcode) {

        /* Converts string to uppercase, checks to see if first character is a '+' for
         *  possible extended format then checks to see if it is a valid opcode if it is
         *  return a 4 else check to see if it is a valid 1 2 or 3 format*/

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inOpcode.length(); i++) {
            inOpcode[i] = toupper(inOpcode[i]);
        }

        if (inOpcode[0] == '+') {
            inOpcode.erase(0, 1);
            opcodes_iter = opcodes.find(inOpcode);
            if (opcodes_iter == opcodes.end()){
                throw opcode_error_exception("opcode " + inOpcode + " not found");}
            else if ((opcodes_iter->second.length) != 3){
                throw opcode_error_exception("opcode " + inOpcode + " is not a valid format 4 opcode");}
            else
                return 4;
        } else {
            opcodes_iter = opcodes.find(inOpcode);
            if (opcodes_iter == opcodes.end()){
                throw opcode_error_exception("opcode " + inOpcode + " not found");}
            return (opcodes_iter->second.length);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution? THis is for a assembler program

Comment: Did you forget `-c` option to the compiler? This code doesn't have a `main`, so it's not a complete program. You can only compile it to object file, not to executable.

Comment: ah This is part of a control section..... Im making a assembler... this specific control section does not need a main....

Comment: The problem in Sun's (Oracle's) linker is that it does not write the error messages correctly (I worked with Solaris 9 and therefore I know the problem): It does not print out which symbol is missing. You may use the "elfdump" command (or GNU's "readelf") to look for all existing and all required symbols in an object file.

Comment: I still can't get it. will the error be in the other two parts of the files you think?